# gradle.lang.MissingPropertyException

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to open my project in android studio SDK but, this **groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'KEY_ALIAS' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.** is ocuring. I don't know how to correct it. Please help.
I am using **Android Studio 3.6.2**
Here is my `build/gradle` file -

buildscript {

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

ext {
supportLibraryVersion = '27.1.1'
constraintLayoutVersion = '1.1.2'
lifecycleVersion = "1.1.1"
butterKnifeVersion = '8.8.1'
glideVersion = '4.7.1'
timberVersion = '4.7.0'
gsonVersion = '2.8.2'
firebaseVersion = '16.0.1'
crashlyticsVersion = '2.9.4'
  }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two gradle file in android project

1) build.gradle (app level)

2) build.gradle (Project level)

the snippet which you posted is a build.gradle (project level). the problem lies in your build.gradle (app level).

**open build.gradle from here**

Open Project structure from your left top bar -> select android -> go to gradle script -> build.gradle

remove KEY_ALIAS from there.